# What is the behaviour when we do not pass the index name while querying from ES

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

Context:
we have multiple indexes in the ES and while querying we are not passing the index name.

```
res, err := s.client.Search(
        s.client.Search.WithBody(&buf),
        s.client.Search.WithContext(ctx), s.client.Search.WithSize(10000))
```

And all the calls are being routed to the index which was created first. Any explanation.

Comment: how do you know this is true - "all the calls are being routed to the index which was created first"?

Comment: This is the behaviour in production in my application.

Comment: so your app does the routing?